# moving elements between arrays in a CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

I am stuck in a very simple thing and I need an opinion. I have a very simple kernel in CUDA that copies the elements between two arrays (there is a reason I want to do it in this way) and

```
__global__ 
void kernelExample( float* A, float* B, float* C, int rows, int cols )
{

    int r = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y; // vertical dim in block
    int c = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; // horizontal dim in block

    if ( r < rows && c < cols) {
        // row-major order
        C[ c + r*cols ] =  A[ c + r*cols ]; 
    }
    //__syncthreads();

}
```

I am taking unsatisfying results. Any suggestions please?

The kernel is called like this:

```
int numElements =  rows * cols;
int threadsPerBlock = 256;
int blocksPerGrid = ceil( (double) numElements  / threadsPerBlock);
kernelExample<<<blocksPerGrid , threadsPerBlock >>>( d_A, d_B, d_C, rows, cols );
```

**Updated**(After Eric's help):

```
int numElements =  rows * cols;
int threadsPerBlock = 32; //talonmies comment
int blocksPerGrid = ceil( (double) numElements  / threadsPerBlock);
dim3 dimBlock( threadsPerBlock,threadsPerBlock ); 
dim3 dimGrid( blocksPerGrid,blocksPerGrid ); 
kernelExample<<<dimBlock, dimBlock>>>( d_A, d_B, d_C, rows, cols );
```

For example having the matrix A

```
A =[
0   1
2   1
0   2
0   0
2   0
0   1
2   1
2   2
2   2
0   0
2   1
2   2
3   1
2   2
2   2   
]
```

the returned matrix C is

```
C = [ 
0   1
2   1
0   2
0   0
2   0
0   1
2   1
2   2
2   2
0   0
2   1
2   2
3   1
2   2
2   2
]
```

Comment: What does "unsatisfied results" mean? Please describe the problem you are having in more detail. It is pretty hard to help you if you don't tell us what the problem is....

Comment: Your "update" can't be correct - a 256x256 blocksize is illegal on every CUDA GPU ever made, so the kernel won't launch.

Comment: Yes you are right talonmies sorry for the wrong info but the kernel it worked, an interesting thing happened. I debugged the code and I noticed that the grid was split in blocks of 1x1 dim. That means that blockIdx.y = 0,...,14 blockIdx.x = 0,...,14 ,blockDim.y = 1 ,blockDim.x = 1 and threadIdx.x = 0 , threadIdx.y = 0. Do you thing that I must update the post? Thanks again.

Comment: Basically I have changed int threadsPerBlock = 256; to int threadsPerBlock = 32;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C/C++ uses 0-based indexing by default.

Try to

1) change from

```
 if ( r <= rows && c <= cols) {
```

to

```
if ( r < rows && c < cols) {
```

2) del `__syncthreads();` since you don't share data between threads

3) correct the block and grid settings from 1-D to 2-D, since you use both `.x` and `.y` in the kernel

4) remove `float* B` if you don't use it.

to solve the problem.

See the kernel `copy()` located in the following file in cuda sample code for more info.

```
$CUDA_HOME/samples/6_Advanced/transpose/transpose.cu
```

Comment: "correct the block and grid settings from 1-D to 2-D, since you use both .x and .y in the kernel to solve the problem." You mean dim3 dimBlock( threadsPerBlock, threadsPerBlock ); dim3 dimGrid( blocksPerGrid, blocksPerGrid ); If yes I did it an edit the example.